# Custom route and query

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql, rest-api, endpoints

I am trying to use a custom WordPress route and function, but I am getting a route and function not found error. Below is my code but I am not sure where it is breaking:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
 register_rest_route( 'boss/v1/latest-quiz-results',array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_latest_quiz_results'
  ));
});
function get_latest_quiz_results() {
 $query = $wpdb->prepare(
 "SELECT post_id, 
   5PxenC_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_key, 
   5PxenC_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_value, 
   5PxenC_learndash_user_activity.activity_id, user_id, course_id
  FROM 5PxenC_learndash_user_activity
 INNER JOIN 5PxenC_learndash_user_activity_meta ON 5PxenC_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_id = 5PxenC_learndash_user_activity.activity_id
  WHERE 5PxenC_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_key = 'pass'");
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
if (empty($results)) {
return new WP_Error( 'empty_category', 'there is no quiz data', 
array('status' => 404) );

}

$response = new WP_REST_Response($results);
$response->set_status(200);

 return $results;
 }
```

Comment: Is that `latest-quiz-results/)` (the route) just a typo in the question?

Comment: @SallyCJ sorry, typo issue. now fixed

Comment: Check my answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your code:

1. The proper syntax of registering your custom REST API route, is as follows:

   ```
   register_rest_route( $namespace, $base_URL, $args, $override );
   ```

   So:

   ```
   register_rest_route( 'boss/v1', '/latest-quiz-results', array(
       'methods'  => 'GET',
       'callback' => 'get_latest_quiz_results'
   ) );
   ```

   Consult the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) for more information.
2. In the `get_latest_quiz_results()`, `$wpdb` is not defined because you're missing `global $wpdb;` at the top:

   ```
   function get_latest_quiz_results() {
       global $wpdb; // Add this.
       ...

       return $results;
   }
   ```
3. Also in `get_latest_quiz_results()`, you incorrectly called `wpdb::prepare()` — the second [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/#parameters) is mandatory, and there needs to be at least *one placeholder* (e.g. `%s`). So for example:

   `$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ... WHERE 5PxenC_learndash_user_activity_meta.activity_meta_key = %s", 'pass' );`